# PHP - MySQL Query assigning same row to two different indexes in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, prepared-statement

I have a query that is supposed to get two rows of data from a database, a and b. When I vardump inside of the `mysqli_stmt_fetch` loop, I get the data of a and b and then inside of the loop, I assign it as a member of an array (`$Array[] = $result`). However, when I then vardump `$Array`, the data for b is in both indexes of the array.

**Expected result** is that the data for both a and b are in the array, but there is just two instances of b's data.

**Code**

```
if ($Query = mysqli_prepare($MySQLObj, "SELECT x.c, x.d, x.e, x.f, y.g, y.h FROM x INNER JOIN y ON (y.i = x.j) WHERE x.k = 0 OR x.k = 1 ORDER BY x.l ASC LIMIT 10;")) // Prepare Query
        {

            mysqli_stmt_execute($Query); // Execute query
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($Query, $Data["m"], $Data["n"], $Data["o"], $Data["p"], $Data["q"], $Data["r"]); // Bind result to array elements

            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($Query)) // Fetch result
            {

                $DataArray[] = $Data; // This doesn't work
                //var_dump($Data);

            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($Query); // Close query

        }

        var_dump($DataArray);
```

Comment: You lost me at a and b

Comment: a and b are two rows within the table x that should be returned

Comment: You can use function array_unique to remove non unique entries at the end. See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: The issue is that I need both rows a and b put into the array, not just two instances of b.

Comment: Can you tell me what that `var_dump` returned?

Comment: @Seti var_dump returned the correct data for one of the rows, but added twice to the array. If I var_dump $Data within with fetch loop, I get both rows data just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normal you can not `_bind_result` to an $Data["m"], $Data["n"], $Data["o"], ... array

you need variables e.g. `$Data_m , $Data_n ....`

but you can set a $variable like that

```
    $Query->store_result();

    $variables = array();
    $data = array();

      $variables[] = &$Data["m"];
      $variables[] = &$Data["n"];
      $variables[] = &$Data["o"];
        ....

   call_user_func_array(array($Query, 'bind_result'), $variables);
```

---

**Update**

If you don't want to set $variables[] by hand, try

```
 $meta = $Query->result_metadata();

 while($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        $variables[] = &$Data[$field->name];
```

Comment: @Ryan : I was also the hope that it works. Once again done it right ;-) ----- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$DataArray[] = $Data;` into `$DataArray[] = &$Data;`  and thats all.